# Find Maximum number of distinct real roots $f(x)$ can have

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

Given that $x=1$  is the root of $f(x)=0$ where

$$f(x)=x^6+a_1x^5+a_2x^4+x^3+a_2x^2+a_2x+1$$ and also given that $f(x+1) \ne 0$

Find Maximum number of distinct real roots $f(x)=0$ can have?

My Try: Given $x=1$ is root we have

$a_1+a_2=\frac{-3}{2}$

Any further clue?

Comment: If $f(x+1) \neq 0$ then how can $f(x)=0$ have any root

Comment: $a_1+3a_2=-3$, I think!

Comment: @KingTut I think OP means that this holds in the sense of polynomials $\Bbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: @Qurultay Unless there is a typo in the question and the OP actually meant  $\,\color{red}{a_1} x\,$, or maybe $\,\color{red}{a_1} x^4\,$.

Comment: What does $f(x+1)\ne 1$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

Since the first coefficient and the constant are 1, the product of all factors must multiply out to 1 for both of them. Sign does not matter as long as they come in pairs to yield a net positive 1 on both ends of the polynomial.

Here is a made up example of 6 roots 1/5, 5, 1/4, 4, 1/2, 2

Granted that 1 is a possible real root but then you would need a -1 to match it and you would need to drop one of my example pairs and have a mismatched sign in one of the two remaining pairs.

While we can have only 6 real roots at a time, the max number or roots possible is countably infinite. For example the roots of

$x^6+121/12 x^5+289/8 x^4+667/12 x^3+289/8 x^2+121/12 x+1$

happen to be [negative]

2, 1/2, 3, 1/3, 4, 1/4   but they could be any combination of complimentary rational numbers

Comment: But $1$ is already a root